# Logical OR CAML Query not working

Tags: caml-query

I have a query that I've written like this:

```
<Where>
   <Or>
     <Neq><FieldRef Name='Status'></FieldRef><Value Type='Text'>Created</Neq>
     <Neq><FieldRef Name='Status'></FieldRef><Value Type='Text'>Updated</Neq>
   </Or>
</Where>
```

Just 1 Neq works (outside of an OR) - but when I do both in an OR - I'm getting back more results than I would expect and some where status is "Updated" (as per value above).

What I am trying to do is:

Get all items where status is not Created or Updated.

Is my logic correct? Is my CAML correct? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [U2U CAML Builder](http://www.u2u.be/res/Tools/CamlQueryBuilder.aspx) (on a tasks list), I get a CAML statement that looks like this, substitute values as needed both for the value type and for the values themselves:

```
<Query>
   <Where>
      <And>
         <Neq>
            <FieldRef Name='Status' />
            <Value Type='Choice'>Deferred</Value>
         </Neq>
         <Neq>
            <FieldRef Name='Status' />
            <Value Type='Choice'>Not Started</Value>
         </Neq>
      </And>
   </Where>
</Query>
```

Or based on your information provided:

```
<Query>
   <Where>
      <And>
         <Neq>
            <FieldRef Name='Status' />
            <Value Type='Text'>Created</Value>
         </Neq>
         <Neq>
            <FieldRef Name='Status' />
            <Value Type='Text'>Updated</Value>
         </Neq>
      </And>
   </Where>
</Query>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want an And. Get all items where status not equal to Created and status not equal to Updated.

Comment: Tried the And operator too, unfortunately same result.

Comment: @JL01, I reckon @Rob Windsor is right: you need **And** logic here. And plus, where is an error in the CAML itself:  closing `</Value>` tags are missed.

Comment: @Omlin - aha I see it now! Couldn't spot it, thanks for the comment!